# Cover a set with multiples

Tags: code-golf, set-partitions

Lets take a set of integers greater than 1 and call it **X**.  We will define **S(i)** to be the set of all members of **X** divisible by **i** where **i > 1**.   Would like to choose from these subsets a group of sets such that

- Their union is the set **X**
- No element of **X** is in two of the sets.

For example we can regroup `{3..11}` as

```
      {3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
S(3): {3,    6,    9,     }
S(4): {  4,      8,       }
S(5): {    5,        10,  }
S(7): {        7,         }
S(11):{                 11}
```

Some sets cannot be expressed in this way.  For example if we take `{3..12}`, `12` is a multiple of both 3 and 4 preventing our sets from being mutually exclusive.

Some sets can be expressed in multiple ways, for example `{4..8}` can be represented as

```
      {4,5,6,7,8}
S(4): {4,      8}
S(5): {  5,     }
S(6): {    6,   }
S(7): {      7, }
```

but it can also be represented as

```
      {4,5,6,7,8}
S(2): {4,  6,  8}
S(5): {  5,     }
S(7): {      7, }
```

### Task

Our goal is to write a program that will take a set as input and output the smallest number of subsets that cover it in this fashion.  If there are none you should output some value other than a positive integer (for example `0`).

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with less  bytes being better.

### Tests

```
{3..11}       -> 5
{4..8}        -> 3
{22,24,26,30} -> 1
{5}           -> 1
```

Comment: *If there are none you should output some value other than a positive integer (for example 0).* Can't our program result in undefined behaviour instead?

Comment: Also, can you add a test case like `[5..5]`? Can we receive things like `[8..4]`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder No it may not.  Programs should be able to identify impossible cases not just loop forever or crash on them.

Comment: "*`12` is a multiple of both `3` and `4` preventing our sets from being mutually exclusive*": why? I don't see anything else in the problem statement which requires `12` to go into both subsets.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I added `[5]` I don't know what `[8..4]` is supposed to mean.

Comment: @WheatWizard [8..4] means [8,7,6,5,4]

Comment: @PeterTaylor It is required to go in those sets. I'll try to work that in.

Comment: Also, what's with the test cases? `[22,24,26,30]` are all multiples of `2`. Are you sure it wouldn't be better to delete this and sandbox it?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thats the same as `[4,5,6,7,8]`, sets do not have order

Comment: @PeterTaylor that should have said one, I must've hit the wrong key when I was copying it over

Comment: @PeterTaylor Does that clarify why we can't add 12?  The wording is very tricky.

Comment: Parameterised names ftw. "*We can define the subset `S(i)` as the set of elements of `X` which are divisible by `i`*".

Comment: Add more test cases please..

Comment: Ah, also needs to require the divisor to be greater than 1.

Comment: Is it even possible to have no solution?

Comment: @Zacharý The example `[3..12]` has no solution as explained.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 167 bytes

```python
lambda a:([q for q in range(a[-1])if a in[sorted(sum(j,[]))for j in combinations([[p for p in a if p%i<1]for i in range(2,1+a[-1])],q)]]+[0])[0]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY05DsIwEEV7TjENkg2DFIcdwUmMC4fEMFG8xHYKTh8SKCh@85f3wzu/vCtHc7uPnbZVrUFfmOzB@Ag9kIOo3bNhWm6E4mRAT55MPuamZmmwrEWpOJ/b7dx@eFuR05m8S0zK8OWEOZmGBsKSrkLNHv3ZJYr1j6@w50qtZaH4pIWJ3gLlJmbvuwRkw/S7GkMkl8EwcmHIjPNRbnGHezzgEU94RlGgEOoD)

-9 bytes thanks to Zacharý
-4 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
-2 bytes by using lists instead of sets
-5 bytes by using `a in [...]` rather than `any([a == ...])`.
-2 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
-8 bytes by merging statements
-5 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
-7 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder / Zacharý
+7 bytes to fix bug
-1 byte thanks to ovs

#### note

This is extremely slow for larger maximum numbers because it is in no way optimized; it did not within 2 minutes on Mr. Xcoder's device for `[22, 24, 26, 30]`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Clingo](https://potassco.org/), 51 bytes

```
{s(2..X)}:-x(X).:-x(X),{s(I):X\I=0}!=1.:~s(I).[1,I]
```

#### Demo

```
$ echo 'x(3..11).' | clingo cover.lp -
clingo version 5.1.0
Reading from cover.lp ...
Solving...
Answer: 1
x(3) x(4) x(5) x(6) x(7) x(8) x(9) x(10) x(11) s(3) s(4) s(5) s(7) s(11)
Optimization: 5
OPTIMUM FOUND

Models       : 1
  Optimum    : yes
Optimization : 5
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.003s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.010s
$ echo 'x(4..8).' | clingo cover.lp -
clingo version 5.1.0
Reading from cover.lp ...
Solving...
Answer: 1
x(4) x(5) x(6) x(7) x(8) s(3) s(4) s(5) s(7)
Optimization: 4
Answer: 2
x(4) x(5) x(6) x(7) x(8) s(2) s(5) s(7)
Optimization: 3
OPTIMUM FOUND

Models       : 2
  Optimum    : yes
Optimization : 3
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.001s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
$ echo 'x(22;24;26;30).' | clingo cover.lp -
clingo version 5.1.0
Reading from cover.lp ...
Solving...
Answer: 1
x(22) x(24) x(26) x(30) s(5) s(8) s(22) s(26)
Optimization: 4
Answer: 2
x(22) x(24) x(26) x(30) s(3) s(22) s(26)
Optimization: 3
Answer: 3
x(22) x(24) x(26) x(30) s(2)
Optimization: 1
OPTIMUM FOUND

Models       : 3
  Optimum    : yes
Optimization : 1
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.004s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
$ echo 'x(5).' | clingo cover.lp -
clingo version 5.1.0
Reading from cover.lp ...
Solving...
Answer: 1
x(5) s(5)
Optimization: 1
OPTIMUM FOUND

Models       : 1
  Optimum    : yes
Optimization : 1
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.001s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
```

Comment: This seems to not detect cases without solutions like `x(3..12).` (or do I need to update?). BTW, can you suggest a good introduction to clingo?

Comment: @ChristianSievers Oops, that was a bug, which I’ve now fixed. It should output `UNSATISFIABLE` in such a case. I mostly used the [Potassco guide](https://sourceforge.net/projects/potassco/files/guide/).

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 105 bytes

```
Length@Select[Subsets@Table[Select[s,Mod[#,i]==0&],{i,2,Max[s=#]}],Sort@Flatten@#==Sort@s&][[1]]~Check~0&
```

***[Try it online](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/)***
copy and paste the code with ctrl+v,
paste the input at the end of the code,
hit shift+enter to run

**input**

> [{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}]

takes a list as input
outputs 0 if there are none

Comment: Nice use of `Check`

Comment: Why didn't you undelete your first answer once you had a working version?

Comment: Because this was a totally new approach? Is there a problem?

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 136 bytes

```
import Data.List
f l|m<-maximum l=(sort[n|(n,c)<-[(length s,[i|j<-s,i<-[j,2*j..m],elem i l])|s<-subsequences[2..m]],c\\l==l\\c]++[0])!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxDoIwFIXhnae4JA4gpUHUxIFujr5B26FikeJtQVoSB94dcdQ4nu/8rfIPjbgsxg79GOCsgqIX40PUAM62yq16GTtZQJb4NeBuThyp0yrnCWp3Dy14ws3cVbknZtWOlNuOUiuJRm3BAMp09us7Xb1@TtrV2vPyE0hSC4GMoRC1zDJeyDSOi8Uq44DBrY8AhtG4ABtogB/l9z5QevqhPaW73R8r5fIG)

How it works

```
f l     =                           -- input set is l
   |m<-maximum l                    -- bind m to maximum of l
       [   |s<-subsequences[2..m]]  -- for all subsequences s of [2..m]
        (length s, )                -- make a pair where the first element is the length of s
            [i|j<-s,i<-[j,2*j..m],elem i l]
                                    -- and the second element all multiples of the numbers of s that are also in l
     [n|(n,c)<-       ,c\\l==l\\c]  -- for all such pairs (n,c), keep the n when c has the same elements as l, i.e. each element exactly once
   sort[ ]++[0]                     -- sort those n and append a 0 (if there's no match, the list of n is empty)
 (     )!!0                         -- pick the first element
```

Take a lot of time for `{22,24,26,30}`.

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, <s>38</s> <s>35</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> <s>31</s> <s>28</s> <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
ṀḊŒPð%þ@⁹¬Sḟ1ðÐḟL€Ḣ
```

-5 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9qZWxsef//4bmA4biKxZJQw7Alw75A4oG5wqxT4bifMcOww5DhuJ9M4oKs4bii////WzMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDksMTAsMTFd)

I **think** the third test case works, but it is very slow. `0` is outputted when there are no solutions.

Explanation (might have gotten this explanation wrong):

```
ṀḊŒPð%þ@⁹¬Sḟ1ðÐḟL€Ḣ     (input z)
ṀḊ                      - 2 .. max(z)
  ŒP                    - powerset
    ð                   - new dyadic chain
     %þ@⁹               - modulo table of z and that
         ¬              - logical not
          S             - sum
           ḟ1           - filter out 1's
             ðÐḟ        - filter out elements that satisfy that condition
                L€      - length of each element
                  Ḣ     - first element
```

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9qZWxsef//4bmA4biKxZJQw7Alw75A4oG5wqxT4bifMcOww5DhuJ/huKJM////WzQsNSw2LDcsOF0)

Comment: Thanks! And thank you for not submitting that yourself!

Comment: I've got a different 18 byte solution closer to my original, I personal like this one better: `ṀḊŒPðḍ@þ@⁹Sḟ1ðÐḟḢL`

Comment: Woah... `ṀḊ` actually is a really cool trick!

Comment: Whoops, that doesn't work, and neither does my rewrite!
[This should output 0, not 1](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9qZWxsef//4bmA4biKxZJQw7Alw75A4oG5wqxT4bifMcOww5DhuJ/huKJM////WzMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDksMTAsMTEsMTJd)

Comment: There, I fixed your solution at the cost of two bytes.

Comment: You can use `L€Ḣ` instead of `Ḣḟ0L`.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 91 bytes

```julia
x->(t=[];for i in x z=findfirst(x->x==0,i%(2:maximum(x)));z∈t?1:push!(t,z) end;length(t))
```

Comment: Um ... did you forget to include a link within the language name, or is it actually named "[Julia]"?

Comment: You are right, the name is Julia without brackets

Comment: You might want to fix that on your other answers as well!

Comment: Wow, that was a lot of answers! And if you want to insert a link, the syntax is `[Text to display](link to website)`